# Java file Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm having troubles loading my program into a linux server. I was able to copy paste my code from my IDE I'm using and have the server compile and run the code, with execution being empty. I changed the lines println to printf and the file will not compile and gives me the error, "Could not find or load main class Program01" every time. Including when I paste my old code that just worked, everything I'm trying is failing. Looking for other opinions on what I can fix. It pulls from an input file with the number "312032486". Just wondering why it is not able to find or load the main class. I believe everything else is working as intended.

Thanks to all who take a look and open to any device as I'm new to java.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package program01;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Devin
*/
public class Program01 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // Create variables for birth rate, death rate and immigration raet
    int birthRate = 1 / 7;
    int deathRate = 1 / 13;
    int immigrationRate = 1 / 45;

    // Variable creating the number of seconds per year
    int secondsPerYear = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

    // Variable to find births, deaths and immigrants added per year
    int birthsPerYear = birthRate * secondsPerYear;
    int deathsPerYear = deathRate * secondsPerYear;
    int immigrantsPerYear = immigrationRate * secondsPerYear;

    // Scanner method to GET population through input.data
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter population: ");
    int population = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Population is: " + population);

    // Math to create variables for population per X year
    double populationYear0 = population;
    double populationYear1 = populationYear0 + birthsPerYear - deathsPerYear + immigrantsPerYear;
    double populationYear2 = populationYear1 + birthsPerYear - deathsPerYear + immigrantsPerYear;
    double populationYear3 = populationYear2 + birthsPerYear - deathsPerYear + immigrantsPerYear;
    double populationYear4 = populationYear3 + birthsPerYear - deathsPerYear + immigrantsPerYear;
    double populationYear5 = populationYear4 + birthsPerYear - deathsPerYear + immigrantsPerYear;

    // Print out the variables data from code above
    System.out.println("Population Year 0: " + populationYear0);
    System.out.println("Population Year 1: " + populationYear1);
    System.out.println("Population Year 2: " + populationYear2);
    System.out.println("Population Year 3: " + populationYear3);
    System.out.println("Population Year 4: " + populationYear4);
    System.out.println("Population Year 5: " + populationYear5);

}

}
```

Comment: what is the command you are using for execution?

Comment: Using a linux server from my school, using a command called SubmitJ. Then it has me select the main class and when I select this program, Program01 it gives me the error. My other 2 main class programs work just fine.

Comment: Do they also have packages? Do you compile to a `jar` or to `class`es? By a server, do you mean an online judge?

Comment: @Devin could you attach another app which you successfully deployed on the server?

Comment: Here's a link to what I see through PUTTY with a linux server. The HelloWorld.Java and JavaApplication1.java both execute flawlessly however Program01 does not. https://gyazo.com/9ca6402b71ee70377a813bad0c899b3b

Comment: can you show their codes? Just HelloWorld will be enough

Comment: @Devin I'm almost sure that you didn't use `package` keyword in the previous assignments

Comment: When I select 1 instead of 3 it executes HelloWorld flawlessly.  https://gyazo.com/fd38795f09f8f3dd10a35cc73c1434c7

Comment: @Devin so I'm correct. Remove `package program01` and it'll work

Comment: Thanks @xenteros! Program executes now, the math is wrong and only outputs the input.data number, however I can go back and fix that now that the program atleast compiles.

Comment: Sorry fixed it, really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your remarks in the comments I'm sure that removing `package program01;` will be sufficient. If your class is in a certain package, you have to place the file in a corresponding directory.

The OP folder structure is:

```
/cs116
    Program01.class
```

so the package declaration is invalid. Removing the package declaration will solve the issue.

Comment: Responded under my own post with a screen shot, the other 2 classes/java files work flawlessly however Program01 does not.

Comment: `java program01.Program01.class` is wrong, you should `NOT` specify class extension.

Comment: This is just stupid. Move class to different package to make it work... How about to fix it rather then move it?

Comment: @rkosegi the issue is with the online judge which seems not to support packaging.

Comment: THis is not related to packaging. You can always run it without moving class to other package.

Comment: @rkosegi it would need to be in a certain directory.

Comment: Yes, it's just a matter of proper JVM arguments.

Comment: @rkosegi and the OP has no impact on the arguments. It's preconfigured online judge environment.